# I have problems converting data using Perl?

Tags: perl

**I want to convert** 
this input `{111,222},{333,444},{555,666}` so that the output be like this `111;222;333;444;555;666`.

```
$Data =";{111,222},{333,444},{555,666};"
Input : ;{111,222},{333,444},{555,666};
Output: ;111;222;333;444;555;666;;;;;;
$Data1 ="111";
$Data2 ="222";
$Data4 ="333";
$Data5 ="444";
$Data6 ="555";
$Data7 ="666";
$Data8 ="";
$Data9 ="";
................
$Data12 ="";
```

**OR** The same thing goes for `{111,222},{333,444}` to `111;222;333;444`

```
$Data =";{111,222},{333,444};"
Input : ;{111,222},{333,444};
Output: ;111;222;333;444;;;;;;;;
$Data1 ="111";
$Data2 ="222";
$Data4 ="333";
$Data5 ="444";
$Data6 ="";
$Data7 ="";
$Data8 ="";
$Data9 ="";
................
$Data12 ="";
```

**OR** and `{111,222}` to `111;222`.

```
$Data =";{111,222};"
Input : ;{111,222};
Output: ;111;222;;;;;;;;;;
$Data1 ="111";
$Data2 ="222";
$Data4 ="";
$Data5 ="";
$Data6 ="";
$Data7 ="";
$Data8 ="";
$Data9 ="";
................
$Data12 ="";
```

**OR**

```
$Data ="; ;"
Input : ;;
Output: ;;;;;;;;;;;;
$Data1 ="";
$Data2 ="";
$Data4 ="";
$Data5 ="";
$Data6 ="";
$Data7 ="";
$Data8 ="";
$Data9 ="";
................
$Data12 ="";
```

input from a machine and I wanted to convert example output and currency by 12 fields even if it is empty whatever the condtion to send it to another machine
I am beginner in perl and thank you for helping me

Comment: Why did you add the `c`, `python`, `unix` and `shell` tags?

Comment: So, why do you have the semicolons in the scalar variable confusingly named $Array? Why do you have the trailing in the Output line, when it's not mentioned in the description of the output? Do you want to produce the output, or populate 12 variables? (BTW, it's much better to use an array instead of 12 variables)

Comment: I want it to be 111; 222; 333; 444; 555 ;;;;; but each value bind a name

Comment: input from a machine and I wanted to convert example output and currency by 12 fields even if it is empty whatever the condtion to send it to another machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore the commas, semicolons and curly brackets, and use a regex match to extract just adjacent digits. I used an array instead of 12 scalar values, as it usually makes more sense.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $data = ';{111,222},{333,444},{555,666};';
my @values = $data =~ /([0-9]+)/g;
push @values, ("") x (12 - @values);
my $output = join ';', "", @values[0..11];
```

The [push](http://p3rl.org/push) line adds the missing empty values so the array always has 12 elements.

The empty string after [join](http://p3rl.org/join) is there to prepend the leading semicolon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer the result is perfect but the problem how to put each value on an example param: 111
in `print Data1 = 111` or `data2 = 222` ...... `data12 = empty`

in the example I try to display `values1` or `data1` but will not work

Comment: Use `$values[0]` instead for Data1 etc.